# Read from Facebook wall (public) in an Android app, without user signing into Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've seen copious discussion about how to extend an Android app so the user signs into their Facebook account, and can then access the graph etc.

However in my scenario the app only needs to access public data, e.g. wall posts from a public figure whose wall is freely available, even on the Facebook web site to people not signed in. I do NOT want the Android app user bothered with requests to sign into Facebook, when they don't need to.

Can you point me to a sample that does this, or some pointers on how to approach this? I have a set of SDKs I can choose from, but want to understand how I will use the API. I assume some kind of authentication is probably necessary so Facebook can track the source of the requests, but the access used must be read-only as the auth details will be distributed inside the app. Hopefully there's something akind to a Twitter read-only application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is something you can do pretty much without using any other API than HTTP found on SDK. You can get public data using plain HTTP/S request and then creating a JSONObject from response;

http://graph.facebook.com/facebook/feed

In which facebook' is the user id.

As for code example should you find good examples for making a HTTP request easily. And for further error checking I would recommend taking a look on [Util](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/Util.java) class in official Facebook Android SDK, parseJSON method especially in which errors returned as a JSON response are handled.

Comment: Hi please give me an example of this url  "http://graph.facebook.com/facebook/feed"

Comment: I am exactly trying to do what the above question is. I got everything u explained, but I dont know for what url I can make http request