# How read public posts on the wall of a public group?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I am trying to read the public wall posts of:
http://www.facebook.com/TheWalkingDeadAMC

It is possible to do this manually in a browser that is not logged into Facebook by simply visiting the above address.

[Using the Graph API, the following link seems most logical](https://graph.facebook.com/TheWalkingDeadAMC/feed?access_token=MY_TOKEN_WITH_ONLY_BASIC_PERMISSIONS) (and seems to be recommended by other users).

Reading the JSON result of the above link unexpectedly provides a list of 24 user comments on an unknown entity. I was expecting to see posts by the `TheWalkingDeadAMC` user on their own wall. Such as:

- 2012-02-15: We just died and went to walker-killing heaven! Gerber Gear is giving away an Apocalypse Survival Kit.
- 2012-02-15: The Walking Dead mid-season premiere episode now on Android, iPhone and iPad.
- 2012-02-14: I'd have to be brain-dead not to want you as my Valentine! Happy Valentine's Day. Send Walker inspired someecards https://www.someecards.com/the-walking-dead-cards

Since this seems like such a simple operation, I must be overlooking something obvious. Any suggestions?

This question is similar to those of:

- http://stackoverflow.com/q/7857610
- http://stackoverflow.com/q/5896700

but I did not find any answers that worked, and I do not have enough reputation to add comments to these existing questions.

Comment: I believe I found the answer on my own. I needed to use the following API link instead: https://graph.facebook.com/TheWalkingDeadAMC/posts?access_token=MY_TOKEN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`/posts`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=TheWalkingDeadAMC%2Fposts) instead of [`/feed`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=TheWalkingDeadAMC%2Ffeed).

See the [documentation on Pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/).

Answer (score 0):

Try querying
 https://graph.facebook.com/TheWalkingDeadAMC/posts

A really useful tool for checking all of the facets of something you can check is the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=TheWalkingDeadAMC/posts)